# Input CSV via ruby into hash than selecting same vaule from hash

Tags: ruby, csv, hash, compare

i am learning Ruby recently, i wonder if i can input CSV via ruby into hash(each line is a hash) than selecting same value from each hash and if there is any value matches than print the key of all same value.

test.csv

> person_name, birth_place
>
> Mary,Indiana
>
> John,Chicago
>
> Sean,Indiana
>
> Jason,New york
>
> Monica,Chicago

ruby code (not finished yet)

```
require 'csv' 
input_file = ARGV[0]
hash = {}
CSV.foreach(input_file, headers: true) do |row|
  row.each do |line|
    person_name, birth_place = line.chomp.split(",")
    hash[person_name] = birth_place
  end
end
```

The result should look like this:

> [{Indiana => "Mary", "Sean"},
> {Chicago => "John", "Monica"}]

Any advise or model?
Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don’t need `CSV` in such a case:

```
hash = {}
input_file = ARGV[0]
File.new(input_file).readlines.each { |line|
  next if line =~ /birth_place/ # ignore headers
  name, bp = line.chomp.split(',')
  (hash[bp] ||= []) << name # create an array if it does not exist yet
}

puts hash


# ⇒ {"Indiana"=>["Mary", "Sean"], "Chicago"=>["John", "Monica"], "New york"=>["Jason"]}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.
I tried your code and use txt file instead of csv file and i got the result as # {} (same us i use csv.file)
Any idea? Thanks

Comment: You should supply a CSV file as an input, because my code relies on comma as separator. To use a text file, you should change splitting to `name, bp = line.chomp.split(' ', 2)` (split to two parts, using space as delimiter.)

Comment: Would you put `puts "Line: #{line}"` line at the beginning of loop body (before `next if …`) and copy the result of execution here?

Comment: Here is the result: Monica,Chicagokme,birth_place
{}